# Confusion with comparison error

Tags: python, list, int, comparison

When i run the following

```python
def max(L):
    m = L[0][0]
    for item in L:
        if item[0] > m:
            m = item
    return m

L = [[20, 10], [10, 20], [30, 20],[12,16]]
print(max(L))
```

i get the error 
 `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()` at line 4. The confusion comes when i try to get the `len()` of both members. So from the error message it's reasonable to assume `m` is the list so i run

```python
def max(L):
    m = L[0][0]
    for item in L:
        len(m)
        if item[0] > m:
            m = item
    return m

L = [[20, 10], [10, 20], [30, 20],[12,16]]
print(max(L))
```

and get the error `len(m) TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. Ok so the only option left is that `item[0]` is the list... so similarly

```python
def max(L):
    m = L[0][0]
    for item in L:
        len(item[0])
        if item[0] > m:
            m = item
    return m

L = [[20, 10], [10, 20], [30, 20],[12,16]]
print(max(L))
```

and i get the same error: `len(item[0]) TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`. Since I'm somewhat certain you can compare 2 ints, I have a hard time understanding what to do about the error originally stated.

Comment: What do you think `len(m)` does? It calculates the length of the list... which you then *ignore completely*.

Comment: ?.... its just meant to see if i get an error as it doesn't work with number data types thus providing the confusion as to why i get error when the compiler states that there exists 1 in the comparison

Comment: Python has an efficient built-in `max` function, there's no need to write your own. But if you want to write your own for learning purposes it's a good idea to give it a different name.

Comment: What are you expecting from `item[0] > m`? One thing is a list, the other is an integer. The error messages you've given are all consistent with that. What result should the comparison give? *"I'm somewhat certain you can compare 2 ints"* - yeah, but that's not what you're doing.

Comment: You didn't tell us what you expect your code to do. Do you just want to find the sublist in `L` with the greatest first element?

Comment: alright, will do. The reason for making the function was to get the max of all left elements of ordered pair `(x,y)`

Comment: again the confusion follows from the assumption that when the compiler states `len(m) TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()` the object `m` is an `int` and the same error message is shown for the object `item[0]` therefore making `item[0]` (under this assumption) an `int` and since you should be able to compare `ints` I'm confused as to why the original error message makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Moses Koledoye says, you are getting that `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > list()` error because the first assignment in the loop assigns the whole `item` to `m`, so the next time you attempt to compare you're comparing the list `m` with the integer `item[0]`. So you just need to assign `item[0]` to `m`. Like this:

```
def max0(L):
    m = L[0][0]
    for item in L:
        if item[0] > m:
            m = item[0]
    return m

L = [[20, 10], [10, 20], [30, 20], [12, 16]]
print(max0(L))
```

**output**

```
30
```

But there's a better way to do this: use the built-in `max` with a key function that grabs the first element from each list in the sequence you pass to `max.

```
from operator import itemgetter

L = [[20, 10], [10, 20], [30, 20], [12, 16]]
m = max(L, key=itemgetter(0))
print(m)
```

**output**

```
[30, 20]
```

You can also do this with a simple `lambda` function, rather than importing `itemgetter`, but `itemgetter` is more efficient.

```
m = max(L, key=lambda u:u[0])
```

In fact, you don't really need to supply a key function here because Python will happily compare 2 lists (or tuples). It compares the corresponding elements in the two lists, stopping as soon as it finds a pair of elements that are unequal. So `[30, 20] > [30, 19]` evaluates to `True`, and so does `[30, 20] > [29, 1000]`. The 2 lists don't have to be the same length; `[30, 20, 0] > [30, 20]` evaluates to `True`.

So you could just do

```
m = max(L)
```

but using `itemgetter` is better (and probably more efficient) because it explicitly says to only compare the sublists by their first element.

Answer (score 2):

In the first iteration of your *for* loop, doing `m = item` makes `m` reference a `list` which afterwards cannot be compared with an `int` (viz. `item[0] > m`) in the next iteration.

You should instead assign `m` to one of the elements in `item`, say `m = item[0]` (to find maximum from first element in each sublist), depending on how exactly you want to compute your maximum value.

On a lighter note, if you're looking for a global maximum, you could simply [*flatten*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) the list and make this easier.